# Get bytes of downloaded file in playwright (example in python)

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation

I am using playwright in python to automate some tasks. At the end, I want to download a file and save it to my cloud storage.

For this, I need to get the bytes of the downloaded file, so I cant post/put these bytes to my cloud api.

I used the very straightforward download method in playwright, as such:

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Download PDF").click()

download = download_info.value
```

I can easily save the file, but can't find anything about get the bytestream. I would expect something like this should be possible:

```
download_in_bytes = download.tobytes()
```

But there is no such method available in playwright.

Does somebody know a way? I can probably save the file first, and then open it again to get the bytes, but I'd rather do it without saving the file in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a way to get the bytes directly, but the closest I could get is the following:

```
# download file
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Download PDF").click()

download =  download_info.value

# save in temporary file
tempFilePath = tempfile.gettempdir()
path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf', dir=tempFilePath, delete=False).name
download.save_as(path)

# load file in bytes
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    bytes = f.read()

# process bytes
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Playwright downloads the PDF to a temporary file/path.

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Download PDF").click()

download = download_info.value
pdf_path = download.path()
```

You could use it to upload your pdf to S3 (for example):

```
s3.upload_file(pdf_path, 'your bucket', 'my.pdf')
```

Done.

Comment: I need the actual bytes, I will test `with open(download.path(), 'rb') as f:
    bytes = f.read()`

Comment: even simpler (and wrapped in io)  `BytesIO(download.path().read_bytes())`